# CreateInputLayout() returns E_INVALIDARG

Tags: directx, directx-11

```
Shader Code 

struct Light
{
    float3 dir;
    float4 ambient;
    float4 diffuse;
};

cbuffer cbPerFrame
{
    Light light;
};

cbuffer cbPerObject
{
    float4x4 WVP;
    float4x4 World;
};

Texture2D ObjTexture;
SamplerState ObjSamplerState;

struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
    float2 TexCoord : TEXCOORD;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
    float4 InstancePos : INSTANCEPOS;
};

VS_OUTPUT VS(float4 inPos : POSITION, float2 inTexCoord : TEXCOORD, float3 normal : NORMAL , float4 InstancePos : INSTANCEPOS;)
{
    VS_OUTPUT output;

    output.Pos.x+=InstancePos.x;
    output.Pos.y+=InstancePos.y;
    output.Pos.z+=InstancePos.z;

    output.Pos = mul(inPos, WVP);
    output.TexCoord = inTexCoord;

    output.normal = mul(normal, World);
    output.normal = normalize(output.normal);

    return output;
}

float4 PS(VS_OUTPUT input) : SV_TARGET
{
    input.normal = normalize(input.normal);

    float4 diffuse = ObjTexture.Sample( ObjSamplerState, input.TexCoord );

    float3 finalColor;
    finalColor = diffuse * light.ambient;
    finalColor += saturate(dot(light.dir, input.normal) * light.diffuse * diffuse);

    clip(diffuse.a - .10);

    return float4(finalColor, diffuse.a);
}

//// creation

D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[] =
{
    { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },  
    { "TEXCOORD0", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT,    0, 16, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },  
    { "NORMAL",  0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,  0, 20, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
    { "INSTANCEPOS", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 1, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA, 1} 
};


hr = D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"Effects.fx", 0, 0, "VS", "vs_4_0", 0, 0, 0, &VS_Buffer, 0, 0);
hr = D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"Effects.fx", 0, 0, "PS", "ps_4_0", 0, 0, 0, &PS_Buffer, 0, 0);


//Create the Shader Objects
hr = d3d11Device->CreateVertexShader(VS_Buffer->GetBufferPointer(), VS_Buffer->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &VS);
hr = d3d11Device->CreatePixelShader(PS_Buffer->GetBufferPointer(), PS_Buffer->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &PS);

//===============Create the Input Layout==================================
hr = d3d11Device->CreateInputLayout( layout, numElements, VS_Buffer->GetBufferPointer(), VS_Buffer->GetBufferSize(), &vertLayout );
```

`CreateInputLayout` is returning `E_INVALIDARG`. I have tried but it's not working. I added the `D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA` flag since I'm working with instances, but it works fine when I remove that.

Comment: Add [`D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476107(v=vs.85).aspx) to the flags argument in your call to `D3D11CreateDevice`, then look in the debug output after the call fails.  You should get more details regarding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the shader compile and the vs_buffer is not nil ? That semicolon should give you a compilation error : `: INSTANCEPOS;)`

The layout setup does not exhibit invalid values that should fail so it is the shader that is not here. Also your texcoord offset should be 12 and not 16 considering the position format, you rendering would be bogus but that technically valid.

Comment: INSTANCEPOS;)  .. it was a typing mistake here.....so dats wasnt the thing...and i changed the offset to 12 was my mistake.... @MooseBoys - thanks for that flag......but now, the layout is created and i can only see 1 object while rendering no instances even its Draw() is been called in a loop

Comment: That's another question that need different context, like how you bind the buffers, so open a new question and link them by adding a reference to each other.